# How can i find a file in a folder structure in python and copy the whole folder where the file is?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a folder structure where I have a few txt files in a few folders, and then I have to copy all the folders where I found txt files to another folder. My root folder is always different, so to find it I use os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)) and search all the folders from there. Unfortunately I'm stuck here, because I never use any file handling in python.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm assuming you have certain folders at a specific location and the folders contain specific `txt` files. Now you want to move all the folders containing text files to a specific location.

You can do this:

1. Walk through all the folders in the master_folder.
2. Walk through files in the sub-folders, and if any file has a `.txt` extension, it moves the folder to the target location:

   ```
   import os
   import shutil

   for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('path_to_master_folder'):

       for filename in files:
           if filename.endswith('txt'):            
               shutil.move(dirpath, 'path_to_destination_folder')
   ```